# Is it possible to use global @validator service in my own service?

Tags: php, validation, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to use global validator service in my own service like this:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
   app.handler.user:
       class: AppBundle\Handler\UserHandler
       arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@validator"]
```

```
# AppBundle/Handler/UserHandler.php
namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class UserHandler
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager,    ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function add(User $user)
    {
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($user);

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

But when I call **validate** method it throws en error:

> Strict email validation requires egulias/email-validator

The version of Symfony I use is 3.1.
Is it deprecated to use **validator** service in Symfony 3.0+?